# Fluent NHibernate issue with creating multi column unique index

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, unique-key

I have the following fluent mapping set up for an entity:

```
        *Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.UserNominee).UniqueKey("UQ_SurveyNominee");
        References(x => x.SurveyRequest).UniqueKey("UQ_SurveyNominee");

        Map(x => x.NominationDate).Not.Nullable();*
```

Unfortunately the unique index is only created on one of the columns on the resulting SQL Server table and not both of them as I expected.  What am I doing wrong?

Regards

mjj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have managed to get this to work but I am not sure why it should make any difference.  I had to change the mapping on the parent "SurveyRequest" entity.  I changed the mapping from:

```
        HasMany(x => x.SurveyAwarenessNominees)
            .KeyColumn("SurveyRequest_Id")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Inverse()
            ;
```

to

**HasMany(x => x.SurveyAwarenessNominees).Cascade.All().Inverse();**

My unique index is now correctly created on the two foreign key columns.

Comment: Further investigation shows that it was the ".KeyColumn("SurveyRequest_Id")" statement in the parent mapping that was the root cause of the problem. The original parent mapping without the KeyColumn part works just fine.